# Would like to know why my answer was deleted

Tags: discussion

My answer was deleted, can I get info on why?

https://askubuntu.com/a/836491/595510

Comment: @mitch this one is for you :)

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm what Rinzwind said in their answer - it doesn't meet the requirements to be an answer.

You indicate in your 'answer' that some PCs have 'power always' USB port, and that BIOS would have to disable it, and that that wasn't working (based on comments from the asker).  Since all you say is "that doesn't seem to work", which echoes the asker, it's not really an answer, and is instead more suited for a comment.  That said, it also doesn't add much as a comment, so it was plain 'deleted', which tends to happen to "not an answer" posts that don't add anything as a comment.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for the bad answer.

Comment: @MarkYisri It's not a problem, and not necessarily bad!  Thanks for contributing to the site, regardless :)

Answer (score 3):

Because it was a comment and not an answer.